# java.lang.VerifyError org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletTransportFactory overrides final method register.()V?

Tags: spring, soap, cxf

i'm trying to develop a  new SOAP web service into my project using **CXF and spring 2.5.6**, but when i deploy the war file into tomcat 6 i got this exception :

```
java.lang.VerifyError org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletTransportFactory overrides final method register.()V
```

i'have done all the configurations into pom.xml, web.xml and application context files. :
 this is the web.xml add lines for the WS :

```
<display-name>CXF Example Webservice</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>

</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and i add these line into the applicationscontext file :

```
 <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />

<!-- Spring manage ServiceBean -->
<bean id="savServ" class="com.otn.sav.SavServiceImpl" />

<!-- JAX-WS Service Endpoint -->    
<jaxws:endpoint id="savService" implementor="#savServ" address="/savService" />
```

i think tha ther is a problem of "versionig" this why java can't load the class :

```
org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletTransportFactory
```

i try it serval times to solve this exception but unfortunately i can't resolve it
if any one can help please answer me ???????
ps : sorry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: look if you don't have some older jar on your classpath - this was my case (not sure how it happened but deleting them helped). Still, it produced another problem.

Comment: thanx Maciek i have resolved the problem by deleting the old jar's of CXF and i add the new one (i get them from a tutorial) to the WEB-INF/lib folder